# VBA using multiple Application.OnTime; one seems to fail

Tags: vba, excel

This is part of a much larger macro that has multiple instances of `Application.OnTime` that work just fine.

My issue with this one below is in `WaitForPriceVolume()` when it gets to the `For Each` loop and the `If` is true, it doesn't go back to the procedure `WaitForPriceVolume()`.  It circles back to all the procedures that were called before, effectively just doing the `Exit Sub` as if the `OnTime` didn't exist.

When I strip out just the below code and add fixed values for the global variables being used, the `Application.OnTime` works.  It's only when I plug it back into the bigger macro.

```
    Sub BDP_PriceVolume()

    Dim lsStartRange    As String
    Dim lsEndRange      As String
    Dim lnStartRow      As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Set sht = Worksheets("Variables")

    ' Use gvList
    lsStartRange = "C" & gnStartRow
    lnStartRow = gnStartRow + UBound(gvList, 2)
    lsEndRange = "C" & lnStartRow

    sht.Range(lsStartRange & ":" & lsEndRange).Value = _
        "=BDP($A" & gnStartRow & "&Variables!$A$2,Variables!$D$2)"

    lsStartRange = "D" & gnStartRow
    lsEndRange = "D" & lnStartRow

    If Worksheets("Variables").Cells(3, 3).Value <> "" Then
        sht.Range(lsStartRange & ":" & lsEndRange).Value = _
          "=BDH($A" & gnStartRow & "&Variables!$A$2,Variables!$E$3" & "," & _
          "Variables!$B$4,Variables!$C$3," & _
          Chr(34) & "BarTp=T" & Chr(34) & "," & _
          Chr(34) & "BarSz=40" & Chr(34) & "," & _
          Chr(34) & "Dir=V" & Chr(34) & "," & _
          Chr(34) & "Dts=H" & Chr(34) & "," & _
          Chr(34) & "Sort=A" & Chr(34) & "," & _
          Chr(34) & "Quote=C" & Chr(34) & "," & _
          Chr(34) & "UseDPDF=Y" & Chr(34) & ")"
    Else
        sht.Range(lsStartRange & ":" & lsEndRange).Value = _
            "=BDP($A" & gnStartRow & "&Variables!$A$2,Variables!$E$2)"
    End If

    sht.Range("C" & gnStartRow & ":" & lsEndRange).Select

    Application.Run "RefreshCurrentSelection"

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "WaitForPriceVolume"

End Sub

Private Sub WaitForPriceVolume()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sht.Range("C" & gnStartRow & ":D" & fnLastRow(sht, "A"))

    Dim cell    As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "#N/A Requesting Data..." Then
          Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "WaitForPriceVolume"
          Exit Sub
        End If
    Next cell

    Call DoneWaitForPriceVolume

End Sub
```

Comment: The Applicaiton.OnTime has a 'Schedule' parameter. Have you tried first setting it to false for "WaitForPriceVolume", then setting it to 'True' with your requested time within your 'if' statement? I suspect that VBA can only have one event per routine scheduled at a single time. I imagine that when you call it via the larger function, the flag doesn't get set back to false until after the routine finishes/exits. Versus if you call it alone, no 'event' is set yet, so it works (once only I bet). TLDR; If you manually clear it, before setting it again, it just may work.

Comment: Try putting `Debug.Print Now, "<Sub Name> Start/End"` at very top and end of Subs to help troubleshoot. Include the value of the Global variables will help too.

Comment: Kris: Clarification. OnTime for WaitForPriceVolume is not used anywhere else.  Was only referencing that other OnTime's were used successfully in rest of macro.

Comment: Patrick: Regarding debug.  Except for OnTime, everything actually works.  I've stepped through the code and the 'If cell.Value = "#N/A" does properly catch.  In all other instances of OnTime in my code on step through, it hits the OnTime, hits the Exit Sub and pauses the x number of seconds and then kicks to the Sub again.  Except in this instance where it just continues with rest of of macro as if the OnTime wasn't even there.

Comment: Own stupidity.  All the other instances of OnTime came at the end of the code, so the macro had nothing left to do until the OnTime triggered and I forced everything to circle back to the main macro.  I hadn't done that in this case.  Problem solved.  This haunted me for a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Own stupidity. All the other instances of OnTime came at the end of the code, so the macro had nothing left to do until the OnTime triggered and I forced everything to circle back to the main macro. I hadn't done that in this case. Problem solved. This haunted me for a week